# What is the type of an Akka (Typed) actor Behavior that handles no messages?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-typed

Suppose I am defining a Behavior for an Akka (Typed) actor that will perform a concurrent computation, report its result to the actor that spawned it, and then stop.

If I initialize this actor with all of the inputs to the computation, plus a reference to its "parent", then it will not ever need to receive an incoming message of any type.

I would create this Behavior with `Behaviors.setup`, passing it a function that performs the computation, and then returns `Behaviors.stopped`.

Akka (Typed) requires me to provide a result type of some `Behavior[T]` for the function that will return this Behavior. And while I could assign to `T` the type of the result message that the Behavior will send, that doesn't seem correct. Isn't `T` meant to constrain what messages an actor can receive? And therefore, if I define `T` in terms of the type of message that the actor will send, am I not "lying" to the compiler?

In fact, this Behavior cannot - and will not - handle any incoming messages whatsoever.

Is there a more correct type that I can assign to this Behavior?

Or am I somehow missing the point of typed actor behaviors?

#### Example:

In the code below, my `apply` returns `Behavior[ Result ]`, but this is a lie. It won't ever receive or handle a `Result` message. (It will only send one.)

```scala
import akka.actor.typed.{ ActorRef, Behavior }
import akka.actor.typed.scaladsl.Behaviors

object ConcurrentComputation {

  sealed trait Result
  final case class Success( result : Double ) extends Result
  final case class Failure( exception : Throwable ) extends Result

  def apply(
    argX : Double,
    argY : Double,
    parent : ActorRef[ Result ]
  ) : Behavior[ Result ] = Behaviors.setup(
    context => {
      try {
        Success( compute( argX, argY ) )
      }
      catch {
        case e : Throwable => Failure( e )
      }

      Behaviors.stopped
    } 
  )

  // Never mind what's actually being done.
  def compute( x : Double, y : Double ) : Double = ???
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general it is used **Behaviors.setup[Nothing]** for behaviors that don´t receive any message. It is supposed that an actor receives messages, but sometimes they don´t. For example, when you create an ActorSystem in Akka Typed you need to provide a Behavior for the user guardian actor, this actor is not going to receive any message, and you create the behavior for that actor as Behavior[Nothing].

This type represents that this actor can not receive any message because "there exist no instances of this type" (Nothing type).

Comment: That makes sense, but when I use this syntax, the compiler complains about the line where I use `ScalaTestWithActorTestKit.spawn( behavior : Behavior[T] )` . (I think because that method defines `T` as invariant.) -> [error] type mismatch / found   : akka.actor.typed.Behavior[Nothing] / required: akka.actor.typed.Behavior[T]

Comment: Aha! If I change the call to `ScalaTestWithActorTestKit.spawn[ Nothing ]( ... )`, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

So far the best I've come up with is `Behavior[ Any ]`.

This is bad semantics, since it expresses the opposite of the code's intent.

Practically speaking, I don't think it can harm the code execution, since no message can be or processed by the Behavior.

Better answers are welcome.